# Bouncing div not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slide, bounce

In my application I have a div that is hidden to 90%. The rest of the div is revealed if you click on the part you see. The div slides down 200px and when it's all down I want it to bounce a couple of times. Below is the code, but by some reason the bouncing doesn't work.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out!

```
    var boxDown = false;

    $('#uploadContainer').click(function(){
        if (boxDown === false) {
            $(this).animate({
                'marginTop': "+200px"
            });
            $(this).effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);


            boxDown = true;
        }
        else {
            $(this).animate({
                'marginTop': "-=200px"
            });

            boxDown = false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use jQuery easing function: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

look at the `easeOutBounce` one

You use it like this:

```
    $('#my-item').animate(
    { 
        'margin-top': -110
    }, 1000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

Comment: Also I think the bounce effect has been moved to jquery-ui (not 100% sure tho). Anyway, I would still use the easing solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the effect you desired, it's bouncing for me: http://jsfiddle.net/drAXv/

I'm guessing that you didn't implement the [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function?

Answer (score 0):

**It should work as expected holyredbeard...**

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veNwd/13/) that depicts your code. All works as supposed.

Maybe you're not loading jQuery UI?